# How to increment Uniques Pallet T::ItemId

Tags: rust, substrate-node, uniques

I have following substrate pallet implementation to split an Item and create new Items

```rust
#[pallet::call_index(26)]
        #[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::split())]
        pub fn split(
            sender_origin: OriginFor<T>,
            collection_id: T::CollectionId,
            item_id: T::ItemId,
            owner: AccountIdLookupOf<T>,
            key: BoundedVec<u8, T::KeyLimit>,
            num_of_nfts: u32,
        ) -> DispatchResult {

            let origin = ensure_signed(sender_origin.clone())?;
            let owner = T::Lookup::lookup(owner)?;

            let collection =
                Collection::<T, I>::get(&collection_id).ok_or(Error::<T, I>::UnknownCollection)?;

            // Current number of items in a collection
            let current_number_of_items = collection.items;

            let item_details =   Item::<T, I>::get(collection_id, item_id).ok_or(Error::<T, I>::UnknownItem)?;
            let mut current_item_id =  CurrentItemItByCollection::<T, I>::get(collection_id).ok_or(Error::<T, I>::UnknownItem)?;

            let item_metadata = ItemMetadataOf::<T, I>::get(collection_id, item_id).unwrap();
            let item_attribute = Attribute::<T, I>::get((collection_id, Some(item_id), &key)).unwrap();


            for num_nft in 0..num_of_nfts {
                let next_nft_id:   T::ItemId  = (current_number_of_items + num_nft) + 1 ;

                // Mint new items
                Self::do_mint(collection_id, next_nft_id, owner.clone(), |collection_details| {
                    if collection_details.issuer != origin {
                        return Err(Error::<T, I>::NoPermission.into());
                    }
                    Ok(())
                })?;
            }

            // Burn parent NFT on success

            Self::do_burn(collection_id, item_id, |collection_details, details| {
                let is_permitted = collection_details.admin == origin || details.owner == origin;
                ensure!(is_permitted, Error::<T, I>::NoPermission);
                Ok(())
            })?;

            /*
            pub fn set_metadata(
                origin: OriginFor<T>,
                collection: T::CollectionId,
                item: T::ItemId,
                data: BoundedVec<u8, T::StringLimit>,
                is_frozen: bool,
            )
            */

            // Self::set_metadata(
            //  sender_origin.clone(),
            //  collection_id,
            //  item_id.into(),
            //  item_metadata,
            //  false
            // );

             // Self::set_attribute(
                //  origin,
                //  collection_id,
                //  Some(item_id),
                //  key,
                //  item_attribute,
             // )?;



            Ok(())

        }
```

I want to increment the current ItemId by 1 inside a loop and mint new NFTs
Unfortunately Im getting an error here.

Error

```
  1573 |                 let next_nft_id:   T::ItemId  = (current_number_of_items + num_nft + 1u32) ;
       |                                    ---------    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found `u32`
       |                                    |
       |                                    expected due to this
       |
       = note: expected associated type `<T as pallet::Config<I>>::ItemId`
                             found type `u32`
       = help: consider constraining the associated type `<T as pallet::Config<I>>::ItemId` to `u32`
       = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html
```

How to fix this error?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1

Change all `u32` to `T::ItemId`.

E.G.

```rs
num_of_nfts: T::ItemId
num_nft: T::ItemId

(current_number_of_items + num_nft) + sp_runtime::traits::One::one()
```

#### Solution 2

Use `saturated_into()`. However, be mindful of the actual runtime type of `T::Item`. Always cast a smaller type to an equal or larger one to avoid losing precision.

E.G `u32 -> u32/u64/u128...`

```rs
use sp_runtime::traits::SaturatedConversion;

((current_number_of_items + num_nft) + 1).saturated_into()
```

Comment: I tried  first approach  but it gives 

error[E0369]: cannot add `{integer}` to `<T as pallet::Config<I>>::ItemId`
    --> pallets/neos_uniques/src/lib.rs:1579:40
     |
1579 |                 let next_nft_id = (current_item_id + num_nft) + sp_runtime::traits::One::one();
     |                                    --------------- ^ ------- {integer}
     |                                    |
     |                                    <T as pallet::Config<I>>::ItemId
     |
In 2nd approach the trait SaturatedCoversion is not available

Comment: use sp_runtime::traits::SaturatedCoversion this is what gets from ChatGPT seems incorrect

Comment: 2. https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/sp_runtime/traits/trait.SaturatedConversion.html

Comment: You missed something on 1. Without the full log I can't help you.